# Dividing a Triangle by Connecting the Midpoints of its Sides

Tags: geometry, triangles

If $T$ is any triangle. Suppose we connect the midpoints of its sides forming four triangles. Does these four triangles have the same angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $ABC$ are the vertex of the triangle and $M,N$ are the midpoint of $AB$ and $AC$ note that :

$$
\dfrac{AM}{AB}=\dfrac{AN}{AC}=\dfrac{1}{2} \quad and \quad \angle MAN =\angle BAC
$$
and  use the criterion of similarity (3) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles) to show that $ABC$ is similar to $AMN$.

You can do the same for the other triangles.